# Why is it that very few questions get up-voted at all?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, banning

I am having difficulties asking questions because of the bans, but I understand why they're there. However, when I look through all the questions getting posted, a scarce few of them seem to get upvotes at all, which is making me wonder if the community users, or voting/banning system is too strict.

Comment: From what I've seen, a scarce few of them have the capacity to be useful to future visitors. Way too many people treat the site like a help desk IMO, which isn't what it's for at all.

Comment: [Nothing wrong with the up-votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813466/up-accept-and-down-votes-over-time#graph)

Comment: @rene what about newly added questions?

Comment: [Because very few questions deserve upvotes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law)

Comment: Should probably include deleted posts in that, @rene, but [it still looks good](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1375382/up-accept-and-down-votes-over-time#graph).

Comment: If I see a question with a meaningful title, the requirement/functionality explained, the code, the inputs, the outputs, a description of what happened that should not and/or what did not happen that should and the merest hint of a debugging attempt, I will upvote it.  Since that happens about once a month, I rarely upvote:(

Comment: Why is it that very few questions are worthy of an upvote?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, Why?

Comment: @jeffthechicken A mismatch in intended use of the site and actual use of the site. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base; one that is pretty well-stocked already so it is very effective for searching purposes. Yet people still see its primary use as asking questions, to get personal tailored support. This is more the domain of other websites which allow things such as discussions and personal guidance but for some reason people still flock to Stack Overflow in droves to ask rather than search. Popularity I guess, it is enticing to ask in a site with millions of active users.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We're a simple people.  We see a well-written or good question; we upvote.